# How to locate what causes memory leak/commit peak?

Tags: memory, commit

I'm trying to figure out what could cause a memory leak but to be honest I'm clueless.

Currently running a Windows 10 H2 build, 16Gb memory, 32Gb fixed swap file (personal preference).

Every now and then (does not look like to matter what I do: just browser etc or gaming) I get a sudden commit peak (memory and swap fills up in this case to 48Gb), then flush back to normal usage. Now this is mainly disruptive during gaming, mostly leading to a drop to the desktop or an alert from the game it ran out of memory. Sometimes every desktop operations leads to the same.

I ran memory diagnostics, no problem, tried testing hardware parts separately and together (like and Aida64 stress test) and no issue. Sometimes does not have any problem for day(s) sometimes multiple times a day. If someone has an idea of what to look for or how to find a solution please help, cause this drive me nuts.

Commit charge peak in PE:

[image: Commit charge peak in PE]

Comment: It might be noteworthy to spell it out that the peak is almost 50 GiB. It is also not visible in the graph. // You could try to correlate the timing with events in Event Viewer and scheduled tasks in Task Scheduler.

Comment: The peak was 50Gb in this case, but only because swap file (min&max) was set to 32Gb. Whatever I set it to it hits it and then flushes .. now to capture / spot it .. that's my issue as it happens randomly, sometimes nothing for days. Is there any way to check what caused it (once it's happened), I mean what program lead to the memory overflow? Something what shows past memory peak usages? Even if I need to run an app 24/7 at least would be able to spot it somehow :)

// edited posting to reflect commit peak, but sadly doesn't matter

Comment: Note that the windows pagefile is not simple swap, but the cornerstone of microsoft's Virtual Memory Management approach. think of it more like a mirror of your ram  rather than an overflow bucket. Neither analogy is entirely apt, but its close enough. using Process Explorer or simmilar, look at Private Bytes to determine the processes impact on the pagefile, and Working Set or Working Set Private to see the processes impact on physical ram. try to identify the processes swamping your system.

Comment: Also note, be careful about the term Memory Leak. it is a very specific type of programming flaw, and is not fixable by anyone other than the programmer.

Comment: I know this, but as I said my problem is that, that it is not something visibly happening or over time. If I should guess the whole memory filling and then flush happens in 1 second, so impossible to spot even if I'm just sitting and watching it. 

Is there any program that would log/save memory usages and when it happens I can check in it afterward what was it?